# Query first letters of each words and full text search in one query

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have such data:

```
Lena
Lera
Elena
Mark
Allen                 
Paul
```

When user enters 'le' I need to return

1. Find words by first letters
2. After that should follow all another words that contains 'le' chars (full text search)

So it should return:

**Le**na
**Le**ra
A**le**n
E**le**na

Something like that (this example does not return anything):

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'le%' AND like '%le%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can put an OR between the two LIKE. But I will always return Alen first.

Comment: First of all, you should compare the search term and the names in uppercase or lowercase. You do not find anything because lowercase `le` is not contained in any name

Comment: But as I remeber SQLite is not case sensitive. And when I enters SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'le%' ORDER BY name ASC  - it returns in right way - lela, Lena, Lera,  etc.

Comment: Well, then maybe your database is configured to ignore case. Anyway, now I saw your error: `WHERE name LIKE 'le%' AND like '%le%'` has to be `WHERE name LIKE 'le%' AND` **`name`** `like '%le%'`

Comment: It skips second part and returns only  'le%' results. Anyway even if it worked in this way I can't sort as planned in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After it turns out that UNION mixes up the order of the sub selects, we'll try something else. You could try it with a custom ORDER BY. First order by whether it starts with your search term, then by name.

```
  SELECT name
    FROM table
   WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('%le%')
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('le%') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         name ASC
```

Comparing the strings with UPPER helps ignoring the case. But UPPER only support ASCII apparently, read [this article](https://techblog.dorogin.com/case-insensitive-like-in-sqlite-504f594dcdc3) for more information on the topic. It also contains other ways to ignore case when comparing strings.

Comment: Thank you. But the query shows an error: "ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before...".

Comment: @alitrun Well, then try wrapping each sub select into `SELECT * FROM (subselect)`.

Comment: You mean first select full search text results, and then select from them words by first letters? But this will be same as 'le%' query.

Comment: I have updated my answer, have you tried the latest version yet?

Comment: Sorry @alitrun, the behavior of UNION differs from whaat I remember: It does not preserve the order of the sub selects. I have changed my answer to a custom ORDER BY.

Comment: Thank you so much Malte! Now it works! You helped many people, because I did not find this question. Words 'THEN 1 ELSE 2 END' this is really sqlite magic :) . Btw in my case (Delphi Firedac on Android\iOS) it works without case sensitivity. Have a nice day!